# update router link params from url

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

Let's say I have 3 route url as following.

```
 <router-link to="/AAA">AAA</router-link>
 <router-link to="/BBB">BBB</router-link>
 <router-link to="/CCC">CCC</router-link>
```

From "AAA" I am selecting one id, let's say project id.

clicking on project from "AAA", I am redirecting to "BBB/Project/454" where 454 is project id.

Now I need to update router link "/BBB" & "/CCC" to be like "/BBB/Project/454" & "/CCC/Project/454". so that when user clicks on those links, project id persists.

How do I achieve this in vue router and router-link?

Comment: Are you using `Vuex`, because  you need to store `id` somewhere?

Comment: vuex is there from vue cli project creation. havent used it.

Comment: Can I use it to write an answer? You should use some store to save your current project id.

Comment: ok, sure. I am not much familiar with vuex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue `router-link` is reactive just like the rest of vue.

You can easily use a dynamic route by passing a variable in like `<router-link :to="myBBBLink">` where `myBBBLink` is the variable holding your desired route path.
Also check out named routes (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html) which might be more appropriate for your use case.

Depending on where your router links reside you can either directly manipulate the `:to` targets or use a global state store (vuex) as EvilArthas has suggested.